# Preserving environment variables in Java

Tags: java, environment-variables

I came through of previous questions published in stackoverflow. Thus, my Java application modifies the System environment, such as:

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
...
...
map.put("SOME_VAR_ENV", "SOME_KEY_VAR");*
```

This seem works fine, since some sentences later:

```
System.out.println(System.getenv("SOME_VAR_ENV"));*
```

prints `SOME_KEY_VAR`.

And, here is my problem. At the next sentence, my Java application yields the control to other Java app. My Java app. invokes to an external Java Class that, as far as I know, it must create a new child process to run on. However, it new process has not preserved the new environment variable (SOME_VAR_ENV).

I have no idea of what's hapening. Why the second application has not preserved the environment? Any idea or help is welcome :)

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the code where "At the next sentence, my Java application yields the control to other Java app."?

Comment: It invokes to an external Class: Session s = new Session(); s.run(params); . I cannot control the flow execution of Session Class, but I want that the s object gets the environment that I have modified.

Comment: Either there is an option in Session to somehow pass the environment variables, or you can modify the code of Session, or you are stuck.

Comment: There are not options to pass the environment variables to Session, and I can't modify this Class. So, I am stuck :(

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) API to start the child process, it lets you set environment variables:

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
 Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
 env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
 env.remove("OTHERVAR");
 env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
 pb.directory(new File("myDir"));
 Process p = pb.start();
```

There is no cross-platform way in Java to set environment variables of the calling context.

Comment: heres a reference too - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html

Comment: You can also do it with Runtime.exec, but the api is a lot worse: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%2C%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29

Comment: I cannot use ProcessBuilder/RunTime, since my Java code creates a new object for externalClass, which represents the external Java application (I guess that it creates a child process, but this is a black-box for me). I cannot control the execution flow of the externalClass. Then, I would like that the externalClass application gets the new environment from my own Java application (I have used a similar code to the provided by Sean).

Comment: @smc as I said, there is no way to do that without hard-coding environment-specific commands. And that's where you need a shell expert, not a Java expert (if it's at all possible)

Answer (score 0):

Look into writing, and then reading, a Java [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) file,